# Como le hago para que una consulta me obtenga por separado mis fechas de mes dentro de sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Actualmente mi resultado es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es que en vez de que me aparezca una columna que diga Mes me aparezca un numero de columnas indeterminado, por ejemplo si tengo el mes de abril, mayo y junio que me aparezcan las tres opciones como columnas y todos los proyectos asociados a esos meses  y si hay 5 meses que sean 5 columnas pero no es determinable cuantos meses habrá en el sistema.

Código actual:

```
select NombreProyecto,case MONTH([Fecha de Corte])
when 1 then 'Enero' when 2 then 'Febrero' when 3 then 'Marzo' when 4 then 'Abril' when 5 then 'Mayo'
when 6 then 'Junio' when 7 then 'Julio' when 8 then 'Agosto' when 9 then 'Septiembre' when 10 then 'Octubre' when 11 then 'Noviembre'
when 12 then 'Diciembre' else 'NULL' end as Mes,MONTH([Fecha de Corte]) as NumeroMes
from PartidasGasto_WS where (NombreProyecto is not null) and ([Fecha de Corte] is not null)
```

Comment: La única forma que puedas obtener un número "indeterminado" de columnas es usando SQL dinámico.

Comment: Solamente se puede realizar utilizando sql dinámico y PIVOT. Además, sería muy recomendado tener una tabla que relacione el número con el nombre del mes (un catálogo) para evitar los múltiples 'when .. then'.

Answer (score 1):

Espero que aun te sirva.

```
create table #PartidasGasto_WS
(
    ID int identity (1,1),
    NombreProyeto varchar (100),
    FechaCorte date , 
    MesCorte int,
    NomMesCorte  varchar (15)
)

insert into #PartidasGasto_WS (NombreProyeto, FechaCorte, MesCorte, NomMesCorte)
select                         NombreProyeto, FechaCorte , datepart (month,FechaCorte)MesCorte,  FORMAT(DATEFROMPARTS(datepart (year,FechaCorte), datepart (month,FechaCorte), datepart (day,FechaCorte)), 'MMMM', 'es-es')NomMesCorte
from
(
              select    'Mulicast Mexder - Format° AS y migration H2H'          NombreProyeto , '2019-01-12 00:00:00.000' FechaCorte
    union all select    'Defensor del empleado - Interfaz de Service Maria'                   , '2019-01-13 00:00:00.000'
    union all select    'Factoraje CFDI complemento de pago'                                  , '2019-01-14 00:00:00.000'
    union all select    '55021 Migration Expresso'                                            , '2019-02-17 00:00:00.000'
    union all select    'Nivelacion de IVR con nuevas fundonalidades/OTP '                    , '2019-02-18 00:00:00.000'
    union all select    'F8CG Soporte Migration 2019'                                         , '2019-02-19 00:00:00.000'
    union all select    'DCC Clk3C PROSA'                                                     , '2019-03-20 00:00:00.000'
    union all select    'CSA GCB 2019'                                                        , '2019-03-21 00:00:00.000'
    union all select    '81447 Sustitucion Terminal financiero Caja en Linea'                 , '2019-03-22 00:00:00.000'
    union all select    'Modification a reportes regulatorios de Transferenc'                 , '2019-04-05 00:00:00.000'
    union all select    'Multivendor'                                                         , '2019-04-06 00:00:00.000'
    union all select    'RAP 4 Venta de Cartera'                                              , '2019-04-07 00:00:00.000'
    union all select    'Vacations'                                                           , '2019-05-25 00:00:00.000'
    union all select    'CSA MX RETAIL 2019'                                                  , '2019-05-26 00:00:00.000'
)t



DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX), @query NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols  =  
STUFF(
(
    select  ','+QUOTENAME(  [NomMesCorte])
    from [#PartidasGasto_WS] c      
    group by MesCorte, NomMesCorte                      
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')  

set @query = 'SELECT NombreProyeto,' + @cols + ' from 
    (  select NombreProyeto, MesCorte, NomMesCorte from #PartidasGasto_WS
) x
pivot 
(   max(MesCorte) for NomMesCorte in (' + @cols + ')
) p '


execute(@query);
```